# Divide clock frequency by 5 in VHDL

Tags: vhdl, clock

I want to divide the clock frequency divide by 5. Can I do it with integer type or do I need something else to run the decimal number?

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

entity divide_clk is
port( clk: in std_logic;
 clk_out: out std_logic);
end divide_clk;

 architecture behave of divide_clk is
signal count: integer range 0 to 24999999:= 0;
signal temp : std_logic := '0';
begin
process(clk)
begin
if (clk'event and clk='1') then
 if (count = 2.5) then
 temp <= not(temp);
 count <= 0;
 else
 count <= count + 1;
 end if;
end if;
end process;
clk_out <= temp;
end behave;
```

Comment: I assume that code is just a rough example of what you _want_ to achieve? Or how do you expect `count` ever to be 2.5?

Comment: First figure out how you would build this with gates and other building blocks. Then figure out how to express that design in HDL.

Comment: What do you intend to do with the clock signal?  Drive logic?  Drive an output pin?

Comment: I disagree with earlier comments. You should never think about gates when writing VHDL, you simply won't beat contemporary synthesizers. Describe the behaviour that you want at the level of a clock cycle and let the tools do the rest.

Comment: @DonFusili, you're disagreeing with a different point to the one ThePhoton is correctly making. The final logic circuit is what matters. So work out what actually can be done to divide a clock by 5 using combinatorial logic and flip-flops - think digital logic. Understand what's possible and what isn't. Don't just write wish-list VHDL. Photon don't mean 'why not design it using logic gates'. Excellent advice: always have an idea of what your circuit will roughly be. Essential in good design, avoids accidental big counters, muxes etc. that drag timing down and consume loads of gates.

Comment: @TonyM I understood the point, I still disagree.

Comment: @DonFusili, sure - I don't know why, though, or why it's a good method. If you have an reply, in light on my comments, I'd be interested in hearing it. Feel free to set up a chat if you'd rather not have a discussion here, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to generate a 50% duty cycle divided clock in VHDL, using only rising_edge of clock, the divided clock's period should be multiples of 2. Since 5 is an odd num, you have to make use of falling_edge of the main clock too. You have to generate two 2/5 duty cycle clocks phase shifted by half period of the main clock. Then you can "OR" it to get the required clock which is of 1/5th frequency and 50% duty cycle.

Something like this:

[image]

Code Sample:

```
architecture Behavioral of divide_by_5_counter is
signal a,b : STD_LOGIC;
signal count_a, count_b : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0);
begin

process(clk_in,reset)
begin
if reset = '1' then
a <= '0';
elsif rising_edge(clk_in) then
if count_a = 5 then
count_a <= "0001";
a <= '1';
elsif count_a >= 2 then
a <= '0';
count_a <= count_a + 1;
else
a <= '1';
count_a <= count_a + 1;
end if;
end if;
end process;

process(clk_in,reset)
begin
if reset = '1' then
b <= '0';
count_b <= "0000";
elsif falling_edge(clk_in) then
if count_b = 5 then
count_b <= "0001";
b <= '1';
elsif count_b >= 2 then
b <= '0';
count_b <= count_b + 1;
else
b <= '1';
count_b <= count_b + 1;
end if;
end if;
end process;

clk_out <= a or b;

end Behavioral;
```

Comment: Is combining falling and rising edge in one design well supported? (I'm not discounting your answer...) In ASIC design our backend folks would complain bitterly, but maybe some/most FPGAs allow it. I understand CTS, cells & flops and see no objection *in principle* of course.

Comment: @P2000 It's supported in FPGAs, but no good designer mixes both edges in an actual design due to timing complexity and power consumption (true for both FPGAs and ASICs). So the above code would be just "academic". If you really want to derive tricky clock ratios, use dedicated IPs is what I would say.

Answer (score 0):

Working on purely the rising edges of your original clock, you won't be able to get a 50% duty cycle. Many circuits don't require this, because most digital logic is designed to only work on rising or falling edges. In that case you can just go for something like this:

```
p_main: process(clk, reset_n)
    variable r_count : integer range 0 to 4;
    variable r_clk_out_i : std_logic;
begin

  if reset_n = '0' then
    r_clk_out_i := '0';
    r_count := 0;
  elsif rising_edge(clk) then
    if r_count = 0 or r_count = 2 then
      r_clk_out_i := not r_clk_out_i;
    end if;

    if r_count = 4 then
      r_count = 0;
    else
      r_count = r_count+1;
    end if;

  end if;
  clk_out <= r_clk_out_i;

end process;
```

If you require a 50% duty cycle, you'll either need to phase shift your original clock or also work on the falling edges of your original clock.

Comment: If precise 50% duty cycle is needed, it is better to use the double frequency and to divide by 5 first and then by 2. Using rising and falling edges of the original clock requires a 50% duty cycle of the original clock.

Comment: @Uwe Agreed, but that assumes you have access to the double clock frequency and then you can just as well divide by 10 in one step, which is straightforward and immediately gives the 50% duty cycle.

Comment: Not all possible methods to divide a clock by 10 in one step guarantee a 50% duty cycle at output.

Comment: @Uwe No, but the straightforward one of counting rising edges of the clock and changing polarity of your output clock on every fifth cycle does. I haven't yet encountered an environment where I'm unable to fit in a 3 bit counter to do this strategy. I'm sure you have, so by all accounts, go ahead and write your own answer which takes into account your own comments. I'm not qualified to put them into my answer since I cannot imagine the scenarios where your comments would apply.

Comment: If a 4 bit counter and some additional logic is used to count in the sequence 0-1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-0-1..., the MSB of this conter has 1/10 of the clock frequency and a duty cycle of 80 to 20 %.

Comment: @Uwe Sure, and if this was still the stone age of ICs, your solution would be relevant. With pretty much every contemporary technology, you can just count to 5 and invert your output clock. Which is what I have already said in my previous answer to your comment. Since you just seem intent on finding something to make hacks relevant in the 90's seem important in 2018, I'll stop responding unless you actually say something of value, if you don't mind.